# Get data using await async without try catch

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, try-catch

I am trying to use await-async without try-catch for this:

```js
const getUsers = async (reject, time) => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (reject) {
        reject(....)
      }
      resolve(.....);
    }, time);
  })
);

module.exports = {
  getUsers ,
};
```

With try-catch block it looks like this:

```js
const { getUsers } = require('./users');

const users = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await getUsers(1000, false);
    .....
  } catch (error) {
    .....
  }
}

users();
```

How can I write the same code without using the try-catch block?

Comment: You will have to handle error somewhere. If you want to avoid try-catch in users function, then you have to catch all possible errors in getUsers

Comment: Here you can do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61833084/6482248 It looks cleaner

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the promise functions then-catch to make the process simpler I use this utils :

```js
// utils.js

const utils = promise => (
  promise
    .then(data => ({ data, error: null }))
    .catch(error => ({ error, data: null }))
);

module.exports = utils;
```

And then

```js
const { getUsers } = require('./api');
const utils = require('./utils');

const users = async () => {
  const { error, data } = await utils(getUsers(2000, false));
  if (!error) {
    console.info(data);
    return;
  }
  console.error(error);
}

users();
```

Without using the try-catch block I got the same output, this way makes it better to understand the code.

Comment: Tried this approach with Mongoose to save data to a collection ~ `.save()` method. Try catch output didn't match. Getting data `undefined` with this approach, while try block gets the correct response.

Answer (score 3):

In Extension to L Y E S - C H I O U K H's Answer:

The Utils Function is actually correct but, make sure to add the `return` keyword before the promise as shown down below:

```js
// utils.js

const utils = promise => (
  return promise
    .then(data => { [data, null]; })
    .catch(error => { [null, error]; });
);

module.exports = utils;
```

When Calling in Main Code:

```js
let resonse, error; // any variable name is fine make sure there is one for error and the response

[response, error] = await utils(any_function()); // Make sure that inside the tuple, response is first and error is last like: [response, error].
if (error) console.log(error);

// -- Do Whatever with the Response -- //
```

Using My Method Would Give you Benefits like:

1. Your Own Variable Names.
2. Not Running into Type Safety issues when using Typescript.
3. Good Reason to Strong Type your code.

Personally, I have been using this in my code lately, and has reduced some many headaches, my code is cleaner, I don't have to stick with the same variable names, especially when working on a large codebase.

Happy Coding :)

See Ya!

Comment: Great response! May I ask if (1) You still use this approach and (2) If there are any issues or gotchas we should know about? I've started using it, and I really do like it!

Comment: @themthem I'm super late for this, but, no I don't use this approach anymore, instead I wrap the await statement in a `try-catch` loop, and handle the error in the `catch` section, this approach is especially good if you're working with typescript.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid default for the error case you can use the `catch` method on the `getUsers` promise and then `await` a promise whose error will be handled

```
const users = async () => {
    const value = await getUsers(1000, false).catch(e => null);
}
```

While this approach should work it should be noted that this may mask the case when `getUsers` returns `null` vs when it raises an error, and you will still need to check for the `null` or get a null access error. All in all I would stick with the  `try { .. } catch (e) { ... }` for most casses

Answer (score 1):

A package I found called [await-to-js](https://github.com/scopsy/await-to-js) can also help it.

```
import to from 'await-to-js';

const [err, users] = await to(getUsers());
if(err) doSomething();
```

The idea is like Lyes CHIOUKH's method, just a wrapper. Copied the [source code](https://github.com/scopsy/await-to-js/blob/master/src/await-to-js.ts) here.

```
/**
 * @param { Promise } promise
 * @param { Object= } errorExt - Additional Information you can pass to the err object
 * @return { Promise }
 */
export function to<T, U = Error> (
  promise: Promise<T>,
  errorExt?: object
): Promise<[U | null, T | undefined]> {
  return promise
    .then<[null, T]>((data: T) => [null, data])
    .catch<[U, undefined]>((err: U) => {
      if (errorExt) {
        Object.assign(err, errorExt);
      }

      return [err, undefined];
    });
}

export default to;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have such above single line `async/await` function, then this would have been clean code for you:

```js
const getUsers = async (time, shouldReject=false) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (shouldReject) {
          reject(Error('Rejected...'));
        } else {
          resolve(["User1", "User2"]);
        }
      }, time);
    });
}

const userOperation = users => {
  console.log("Operating user", users);
}

// Example 1, pass
getUsers(100)
    .then(users => userOperation(users))
    .catch(e => console.log(e.message));

// Example 2, rejected
getUsers(100, true)
    .then(users => userOperation(users))
    .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```

And for multiple `await` in a single `async` function, it would good to have try/catch block as below:

```
const users = async () => {
    try {
        const value = await getUsers(1000, false);
        const value1 = await getUsers2(1000, false);
        ...
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
}
```